# dynamic panelMenu in richfaces

Tags: dynamic, richfaces, jpanelmenu

I am trying to create a `panelMenu` dynamically using a list of items I have already.
But it doesn't seem to work as I get nothing as result.
So here is my code:

```
<rich:panelMenu id="filterListFuncPost" style="width:180px"
    itemMode="ajax" groupMode="ajax"
    groupExpandedLeftIcon="triangleUp"
    groupCollapsedLeftIcon="triangleDown"
    topGroupExpandedRightIcon="chevronUp"
    topGroupCollapsedRightIcon="chevronDown" itemLeftIcon="disc">
        <rich:panelMenuGroup label="Functional Positions">
            <c:forEach xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" var="item"
                items="#{reportsBacking.selectedFunctPosIndex}">
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{item}" />
            </c:forEach>
        </rich:panelMenuGroup>

</rich:panelMenu>
```

Comment: Have you checked the resulting HTML? What does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

For whom it might help, I found a way to make it work which is to use a `rich:list` instead of `c:forEach` and it works fine.

Comment: `c:forEach` is a tag handler, which operates during view-build and as a result, probably too early for it to have access to the content of `reportsBacking`. `rich:List` is a ui-component, operating *after* view build, in time to have access to the right variable. You could easily substitute `ui:repeat` for `rich:List` here as a result

Comment: I might try your approach using rich:List. Thanks! It didn't work using ui:repeat - see alternate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Does work for RichFaces panelMenu, but only if you use the right iterator. I returned to this problem with fresh eyes and found a fairly obvious solution, but it doesn't appear to be out there on the internets yet so here it is:

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"

<rich:panelMenu id="menuRoot">
    <rich:panelMenuGroup id="lev1menu">
        <c:forEach var="fancyGroup" items="#{myBean.myFancyGroupEntity}">
            <rich:panelMenuGroup label="#{fancyGroup.name}" id="lev2menu_#{fancyGroup.id}">
                <c:forEach var="fancyItem" items="#{fancyGroup.items}">
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{fancyItem.name}" action="#{myBean.viewItem}">
                        <a4j:actionParam name="itemId" value="#{fancyItem.id}"/>
                    </rich:panelMenuItem>
                </c:forEach>
            </rich:panelMenuGroup>
        </c:forEach>
    </rich:panelMenuGroup>
</rich:panelMenu>
```

Why does it work? Beacuse the JSTL core components are parsed and processed before the JSF components (or something like that) and so the c:forEach renders out all the RichFaces (or other JSF) child components prior to JSF being parsed and processed. Hence the panelMenu has children of correct type by the time it gets parsed.

OLD: Won't work with RichFaces panelMenu (`org.richfaces.component.UIPanelMenu`) component.

I tried a similar approach using database items to dynamically generate a hierarchy of menus but when it attempts to parse it on the server side RichFaces tries to cast any children to be either panelMenuGroup or panelMenuItem and fell over with a `ClassCastException` trying to cast from `com.sun.facelets.component.UIRepeat`, which would be the same for your JSTL forEach iteration component (which is an instance of `org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag` on the server, I think).